# Does the order of `const` and e.g. `int` make a difference in C?

Tags: c++, c

I've looked around C and C++ FAQs and tutorials and haven't been able to find a clearcut answer.

What difference, if any, does it make to write:

```
const int i;
int const j;
```

While we are at it, is there any difference between

```
const int a[10];
int const b[10];
```

(Yes, I know about e.g. `const int *p` and `int *const q`, the first is a mutable pointer to a constant object, the second is a constant pointer to a mutable object).

Comment: No, it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: The three qualifiers `const`, `volatile`, `restrict` and the order next to a type name makes no difference.

`const` _typename_ matches the style in the C spec.

Comment: One rmark. Order maters in more complex declarations. for example `const int * ptr;` is not the same as `int * const ptr`

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in meaning as defined by the C standard or the C++ standard.

Regarding the C standard, I do not see any explicit statement that the order of declaration specifiers is irrelevant except for type specifiers. That it is irrelevant is simply a product of how the meanings are specified:

- A declaration has a list of specifiers, which may include storage class specifiers (like `static`), type specifiers (like `int`), qualifiers (like `const`), function specifiers (like `inline`), and others.
- The clauses that specify the effects of these specifiers simply say what they do if they are present. They do not say any effects are dependent on order.
- The clause covering type specifiers explicitly mentions the type specifiers may be in any order (such as `long int long`) and may be intermixed with other declaration specifiers.

Note that the pointer indicator, `*`, is not part of the declaration specifiers. It is part of a declarator, along with `[…]` to indicate an array and `(…)` to indicate a function. Qualifiers appearing after a `*` are part of the declarator and are not part of the list of specifiers for the declaration proper. In simplified form, a declaration is “*space-separated-list-of-specifiers* *comma-separated-list-of-declarators* `;`”. That initial list of specifiers may be in any order.